# Accessing Selected item value from drop down list in knock out js

Tags: knockout.js

By a lot of experiments I could bind my first drop down list. So my next step is to select a value of Drop down list. I followed below manner.

```
 <div id="divcountry">          
            <span>Country&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>&nbsp;
              <select   data-bind="options: CountriesList,optionsText: 'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryId',value:CountryId,optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'" style="width: 148px">
            </select>
            </div>

 var countryModel = {

          CountriesList: ko.observableArray([])

      };


      var countryViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.CountryModel = countryModel;
          // self.validateCountry = ko.validation.group(self.CountryModel, { deep: true });
          self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.CountryId = ko.observable();

      }

      var stateModel = {
          StateId: ko.observable(0),
          StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
          ShortName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
          IsActive: ko.observable(true),


          CountryId: ko.observable()
      };

      var stateViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.StateModel = stateModel;
         // self.validateState = ko.validation.group(self.CountryModel, { deep: true });
          self.StatesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          //Handle Submit
          self.Submit = function () {
             // if (self.validateCountry().length == 0) {
                  if (self.StateModel.StateId() > 0) {
                      self.UpdateCountry();
                  } else {
                      self.AddState();
                  }
                 // self.Reset();
              }
        //  }
```

Now my doubt is nothing but can we access the `countryViewModel` data which is `self.CountryId` in my StateModel??
Please I want to send `CountryId` to the server side code!!

Answer (score 0):

Your stateViewModel seems incomplete, but if you have both a state and country model, you could subscribe to changes in the country and update the state:

```
self.StateModel = stateModel;
self.CountryModel = countryModel;
self.CountryModel.CountryId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    self.StateModel.CountryId(newValue);
});
```

Comment: @Aj_sari Ok, fine, but that doesn't change the answer, just a minor tweak to the least significant part of the code. I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get your desired results

```
var countryViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.CountryModel = countryModel;
          // self.validateCountry = ko.validation.group(self.CountryModel, { deep: true });
          self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray([]);
          self.CountryId = ko.observable().subscribe(function(newValue){
          stateModel.CountryId(newValue);
          });
      }
```

Comment: will it gives me selected item value in drop down list?

Comment: Actually i dont understand why you are adding self.CountryId in CountryView model, because here i want to store the stateview model in which there is one parameter called countryid which is present in country view model